# Getting the part for string using sql server query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have rows like below

```
10470_AMK-4799__OFS_BROWSERTC
6038_DMUSER_DM.READ.REPLACEMENT
6043_DMUSER2__OFS_DM.OFS.SRC.VAL
10194_AMK-TC037__OFS_BROWSERTC
64948_AMK-TABLETUSER__OFS_TWS
10010_AMK-0357
```

I want to write a query which can produce the part of string like below (from the first underscore up to the second, both not included):

```
AMK-4799
DMUSER 
DMUSER2
AMK-TC037
AMK-TABLETUSER
AMK-0357
```

I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2014.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want data between first instance of `_` and second instance of `_` OR length of string in-case second `_` is not present.

Try this Query:

```
-- Create Table Variable
DECLARE @tblString TABLE(StringVal VARCHAR(512));
-- Insert Values in Table Variable
INSERT INTO @tblString(StringVal)
select '10470_AMK-4799__OFS_BROWSERTC' UNION ALL
select '6038_DMUSER_DM.READ.REPLACEMENT' UNION ALL
select '6043_DMUSER2__OFS_DM.OFS.SRC.VAL' UNION ALL
select '10194_AMK-TC037__OFS_BROWSERTC' UNION ALL
select '64948_AMK-TABLETUSER__OFS_TWS' UNION ALL
select '10010_AMK-0357';
-- Select and process for expected Result
SELECT SUBSTRING(
                  SUBSTRING(StringVal,CHARINDEX('_',StringVal,0)+1,LEN(StringVal))
                ,0
                ,CASE when CHARINDEX('_',SUBSTRING(StringVal,CHARINDEX('_',StringVal,0)+1,LEN(StringVal))) <> 0
                    then CHARINDEX('_',SUBSTRING(StringVal,CHARINDEX('_',StringVal,0)+1,LEN(StringVal)))
                    else LEN(StringVal) as Result
                end
                )
FROM @tblString
```

The results are as below:

```
Result
-------
AMK-4799
DMUSER
DMUSER2
AMK-TC037
AMK-TABLETUSER
AMK-0357
```

This will achieve current scope.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @table TABLE(id_name VARCHAR(1000))

INSERT INTO @table
(
      id_name
)
select '10470_AMK-4799__OFS_BROWSERTC' UNION ALL
select '6038_DMUSER_DM.READ.REPLACEMENT' UNION ALL
select '6043_DMUSER2__OFS_DM.OFS.SRC.VAL' UNION ALL
select '10194_AMK-TC037__OFS_BROWSERTC' UNION ALL
select '64948_AMK-TABLETUSER__OFS_TWS'

SELECT SUBSTRING(
                  SUBSTRING(id_name,CHARINDEX('_',id_name,0)+1,LEN(id_name)),0,CHARINDEX('_',SUBSTRING(id_name,CHARINDEX('_',id_name,0)+1,LEN(id_name)))) 
FROM @table
```